# I have a 'Segmentation Problem' while printing parsed parts of a String

Tags: c

I am writing a simple Shell for school assignment and stuck with a segmentation problem. Initially, my shell parses the user input to remove whitespaces and endofline character, and seperate the words inside the input line to store them in a `char **args` array. I can seperate the words and can print them without any problem, but when storing the words into a `char **args` array, and if argument number is greater than 1 and is odd, I get a segmentation error.

I know the problem is absurd, but I stuck with it. Please help me.

This is my parser code and the problem occurs in it:
[image: Screenshot]

```
char **parseInput(char *input){
int idx = 0;
char **parsed = NULL;
int parsed_idx = 0;

while(input[idx]){
    if(input[idx] == '\n'){
        break;

    }
    else if(input[idx] == ' '){
        idx++;

    }
    else{
        char *word = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
        int widx = 0; // Word index
        word[widx] = input[idx];
        idx++;
        widx++;
        while(input[idx] && input[idx] != '\n' && input[idx] != ' '){
            word = (char*)realloc(word, (widx+1)*sizeof(char*));
            word[widx] = input[idx];
            idx++;
            widx++;
        }

        word = (char*)realloc(word, (widx+1)*sizeof(char*));
        word[widx] = '\0';
        printf("Word[%d] --> %s\n", parsed_idx, word);

        if(parsed == NULL){
            parsed = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char**));
            parsed[parsed_idx] = word;
            parsed_idx++;
        }else{
            parsed = (char**) realloc(parsed, (parsed_idx+1)*sizeof(char**));
            parsed[parsed_idx] = word;
            parsed_idx++;
        }

    }
}
int i = 0;

while(parsed[i] != NULL){
    printf("Parsed[%d] --> %s\n", i, parsed[i]);
    i++;
}

return parsed;
```

}

Comment: The `malloc` function requires the size in bytes to allocate. For a dynamically allocated array that's usually the number of elements multiplied with the size of a single element. For a string the single element is a single `char`, which is `sizeof(char)` (which is always equal to `1`) not `sizeof(char *)` (which will typically be either `4` or `8` depending on platform). That makes `char *word = malloc(sizeof(char*));` wrong, it should be `char *word = malloc(sizeof(char));` (or just plain `char *word = malloc(1);`).

Comment: A possible hint about your problem: When do you ever assign `NULL` to `parsed[parsed_idx]`?

Comment: And lastly a definitive hint about your problem: Use a debugger to catch the crash as and when it happen, to find out where in your code it happens and what the values of all involved variables are at that point.

Comment: I am suspicious of how you turned char **argv into char * . . . can you please show that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your return, I've missed out the malloc problem. Problem still remains. I am using a debugger. It seems the problem is the allocation of 'parsed'. There is an unnecessarily created one more parsed object. I couldn't where it is happening in the code but I'm working on it. :)

Comment: @FrankMerrow This is a shell implementation, I didn't get the arguments from terminal, but stdin with getline().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have the loop

```
while(parsed[i] != NULL) { ... }
```

The problem is that the code never sets any elements of `parsed` to be a `NULL` pointer.

That means the loop will go out of bounds, and you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to explicitly set the last element of `parsed` to be a `NULL` pointer after you parsed the input:

```
while(input[idx]){
    // ...
}

parsed[parsed_idx] = NULL;
```

---

On another couple of notes:

- Don't assign back to the same pointer you pass to [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc). If `realloc` fails it will return a `NULL` pointer, but *not* free the old memory. If you assign back to the pointer you will loose it and have a memory leak. You also need to be able to handle this case where `realloc` fails.
- A loop like

  ```
  int i = 0;

  while (parsed[i] != NULL)
  {
      // ...
      i++;
  }
  ```

  is almost exactly the same as

  ```
  for (int i = 0; parsed[i] != NULL; i++)
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```

  Please use a `for` loop instead, it's usually easier to read and follow. Also for a `for` loop the "index" variable (`i` in your code) will be in a separate scope, and not available outside of the loop. Tighter scope for variables leads to less possible problems.
- In C you [shouldn't really cast the result of `malloc` (or `realloc`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (or really any function returning `void *`). If you forget to `#include <stdlib.h>` it could lead to hard to diagnose problems.

Answer (score 1):

Also, a beginner might find the -pedantic switch helpful on your call to the compiler.  That switch would have pointed up most of the other suggestions made here.  I personally am also a fan of -Wall, though many find it annoying instead of helpful.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion :)